# IE equivalent to the PixelPerfect plugin for FireBug

Tags: css, firebug

I use the PixelPerfect plugin for FireBug to tweak my XHTML/CSS-page to match a given design template. I wondered if there is a similar way to do this in IE6+?

Answer (score -1):

You could use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html), but its not as useful as [the real deal](http://getfirebug.com/).

Just put this bookmarklet in your address bar, and you are ready to go:

```
javascript:var%20firebug=document.createElement('script');firebug.setAttribute('src','http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js');document.body.appendChild(firebug);(function(){if(window.firebug.version){firebug.init();}else{setTimeout(arguments.callee);}})();void(firebug);
```

Comment: Sadly, there isn't a port of PixelPerfect for Firebug Lite.